# form-control with select tag in Mozilla Firefox displays text but the same component in Chrome doesn't

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-select

I am using **Angular 5.x** with `select` tag and `optgroup` along side `Bootstrap 4.1.x`

My `component.html` is as follows:

```
                    <select size="15" class="form-control mr-4">
                        <optgroup label="Properties">
                            <option *ngFor="let eachVal of dataResults"
                                    [selected]="searchModel.translatedProperty===eachVal.translatedProperty"
                                    (click)="getPropertyValues(eachVal)">
                                <span>{{eachVal.translatedProperty}}</span>
                            </option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="References">
                            <option *ngFor="let eachVal of objResults; let i=index;"
                                    [selected]="searchModel.translatedProperty===eachVal.translatedProperty"
                                    (click)="getReferenceValues(eachVal, i)">
                                <span>{{eachVal.translatedProperty}}</span>
                            </option>
                        </optgroup>
```

I use `form-control` as a class to `select` as mentioned in the Bootstrap Forms Documentation [source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/)

This renders a list as follows:

### Mozilla Firefox

In Mozilla Firefox `v.60.0.2`

[image: FIREFOX RENDERING]

On the contrary

### Google Chrome

The text is there but it renders not in the black font color
[image: GOOGLE CHROME]

What is causing this rendering problem. I do not have any overrriden `styles.css`.

What is the `css` to make sure the `select` tag lists renders throughout all Browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

By removing the `<span>` tags within the `<option>` tags displays the text again.

Checks have been made on :

- **Mozilla Firefox**
- **Google Chrome**
- **Microsoft Edge**